# Can't read/write files when using UWP broadFileSystemAccess restricted permission

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm building an internal company app and trying to read and write files on local and network drives. I have added the `broadFileSystemAccess` restricted capability. I am able to list directories, but I get `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` when trying to read or write any files.

I have found that if I also add file type associations for the types of files I am reading or writing, then it works. However, this also means that the app gets registered with Windows to open those file types, which I do not want.

```
// This line works once I enable broadFileSystemAccess.
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"Path\to\folder");

// This line works only after I add a pdf file type association.
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"Path\to\file.pdf");
```

Comment: From documentation : Note: You must add the file type associations to the manifest of the declaration application.

Comment: Are you sure you have actually enabled broad filesystem access for your app in the system settings? Check Settings->Privacy->File System - look for your app and make sure its setting is "On".

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Nope! Thanks, I'm guessing that's the issue. As I commented on Nico's answer though, my app isn't in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Stefan Wick MSFT said, after add `broadFileSystemAccess` capability, you also need to manually enable broad file system in File System setting page. For getting the setting page, you could search **file system** keywords in setting app home page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is my problem. However, "Allow apps to access your file system" is on, but I don't see my app in the "Choose which apps can access your file system" list. I just tried bundling and side-loading and it's still not in that list.

Comment: Are you sure the capability is declared in the appxmanifest file that gets deployed? Double-check by navigating to the install location and inspect the appxmanifest there.

Comment: Thanks! It was there, but that led me to discover that I had a rogue ` &gt;` in the xmlns:rescap url. No idea how that got there, but now everything is working as it should.