# Retrieving the amount of local storage on a device in UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have been trying to find the amount of free storage space available in the fixed drive on a device in my UWP app. I have been using the following code to achieve this-

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
    if (d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed && d.IsReady)
    {
        double availableFreeSpaceInBytes = d.AvailableFreeSpace;
    }
}
```

But whenever I run this, d.IsReady always returns false indicating that the device is not ready. I referred this- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.isready?view=netframework-4.8. But haven't been able to understand.

Please help me with what am I doing wrong. Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Retrieving the amount of local storage on a device in UWP app

`AvailableFreeSpace` is not available in UWP system. For getting available free space, you need use `StorageFolder` [**System.FreeSpace**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/props-system-freespace) property to achieve. Pleas note if you used `GetFolderFromPathAsync` metod, you need to allow [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) capability before. Please refer this case [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860493/cant-read-write-files-when-using-uwp-broadfilesystemaccess-restricted-permissio/53862018#53862018).

```
const String k_freeSpace = "System.FreeSpace";
const String k_totalSpace = "System.Capacity";
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Drive: " + d.Name);
        Debug.WriteLine("RootDir: " + d.RootDirectory.FullName);

        StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(d.RootDirectory.FullName);
        var props = await folder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { k_freeSpace, k_totalSpace });
        Debug.WriteLine("FreeSpace: " + (UInt64)props[k_freeSpace]);
        Debug.WriteLine("Capacity:  " + (UInt64)props[k_totalSpace]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Couldn't get info for drive {0}.  Does it have media in it?", d.Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: I only want to print the free storage available on the user's machine. Is this the only way to achieve this? Is there any other way to achieve this which does not require allowing broadFileSystemAccess capability.

Comment: @nico-zhu-msft can I use this instead?

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to know the free space on the drive where your UWP app is installed (usually, the C: drive), you can use the following without adding any additional capabilities:

```
using Windows.Storage;

string freeSpaceKey = "System.FreeSpace";
var retrieveProperties = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { freeSpaceKey });
var freeSpaceRemaining = (ulong)retrieveProperties[freeSpaceKey];
```

Comment: Take the bytes you get from the code above, then divide by 1024*1024*1024.  The numbers should (nearly) match.