# Creating new directory returns error :"System.UnauthorizedAccessException : 'Access to the path 'C:\Users' is denied.'

Tags: c#, uwp, directory

I'm making a small `UWP` program which will have a `config.xml` file.
I want this one to be saved in the "My Games\My application\" folder.

This is the code I use :

```
string folder = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\My Games\\MyAppFolder";
Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
```

When running the program, the second line gives this error :

> "System.UnauthorizedAccessException : 'Access to the path 'C:\Users' is denied.'".

I tried with

```
string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\My Games\\MyAppFolder"
```

and

```
string folder = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\MyAppFolder";
```

and got the same issue.

However, I tried with a `C#` `winforms` application where I didn't have any issue : there, the same code works perfectly, the new folder is created.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think I found why I cannot do this : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Creating new directory returns error :"System.UnauthorizedAccessException : 'Access to the path 'C:\Users' is denied.'

UWP is running on sandbox, you could not use `System.IO` api(`Directory.CreateDirectory`) to access folder path directly, and you need use [`Windows Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) api to access the specific folder. For access such path `C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\MyAppFolder`, you also add `broadFileSystemAccess` capability and open this permission in the file setting. For more please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860493/cant-read-write-files-when-using-uwp-broadfilesystemaccess-restricted-permissio/53862018#53862018)

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```