# Check if folder pointed by StorageFolder still exist

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-runtime

How can I check if a folder pointed by a StorageFolder still exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your app has the [appropriate permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53862018/7252182), you could use the `StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync` API.

The following sample code is in C# but should give you the idea:

```
public static async Task<bool> ExistsAsync(StorageFolder folder)
{
    try
    {
        await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(folder.Path);
        return true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is the best solution I have found.